# Как узнать наличие конкретного ключа в JSONObject?

Tags: android, json

Есть json файл вида:

```
{
"kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
"etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/sQScxznVlWgD1fXmkY5DK6q8la8\"",
"nextPageToken": "CAkQAA",
"prevPageToken": "CAYQAQ",
"pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": 4348,
 "resultsPerPage": 3
 },
```

но при определённых обстоятельствах этот файл может не содержать одну пару ключ/значение и будет иметь вид:

```
{
"kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
"etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/LDtQl6zDAmdnv2VvMnzfjox4-9w\"",
"nextPageToken": "CAMQAA",
"pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": 4348,
 "resultsPerPage": 3
},
```

Вопрос: Как узнать, что JSONObject содержит пару ключ "prevPageToken"?

Спасибо.

Comment: [Документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) читали? rtfm **has(String name)/isNull(String name)**

Comment: Вы думаете, что я идиот? Да, я идиот. Спасибо. :)

Answer (score 3):

Я сделал так:

```
dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
if (dataJsonObj.has("prevPageToken"))
    //Тут какой-то код, если истина
else
    //Тут какой-то код, если ложь
```

В общем и целом всё элементарно. Читать [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)